# How to css this little button next to <select> element?

Tags: html, css, select, button

i wanna to change style (background, etc) of the little button with arrow that is on left side of < select > tag. Anyone know if it is possible and how to do that?

Comment: Can you make a simple sketch?

Comment: No, you can't properly style the little arrow on a `<select>` tag. You must instead use a javascript dropdown.

Comment: Here's a related thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript

Comment: Doesn't look like a duplicate. This is asking on that button, the linked question is asking about the whole dropdown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not aware of any good cross-browser methods to style a select box with just css, but I have had success in the past with this using jquery ui

http://filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/